# 403 Forbidden when trying to access node server on AWS instance, through proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I am using Node.js + Socket.io in my application.

Say, my chat application (php) is hosted on `server A` and node.js is hosted on `AWS`.

Each client accesses chat application and in the background it registers the client with the node.js application hosted on AWS.

The problem is when I use a proxy server from `hidemyass.com` and configure my firefox to access the application.

The application is loading but it unable to connect to node server hosted on AWS and I get a `403 Forbidden error`.

Is this a problem with AWS security configuration or a node.js settings ? I am unable to figure this at all.

I have tried my best to search for reasons why this would happen, but didn't get any clue. Can it be an AWS configuration issues or Is it to do with Nodejs server settings. Any guess or help is highly appreciated.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: just a guess, but are all the required ports open? AWS only have 22 open by default and a proxy might block any port but 80?

Comment: Thanks for the guess Gergely, But I checked, all the ports are open. :(

Comment: Is it possible to have a look at the app and the error? My 2nd guess would be that you get the 403 error because you try to load JS from a different domain. Could this be any help: http://serverfault.com/questions/445090/i-get-a-403-when-requesting-a-js-file-from-cloudfront

Comment: Same issue on socket.IO web site ;( fallback to long polling